# Photo slideshow

Tags: html, css

I am building a photo gallery in php. I have done all things the thing I want is to create a scrolling filmstrip which will show my photos in it. The problem is I have got a readymade slideshow downloaded from the internet which contains several files. Now I want to know if I can use iframes to put up the slideshow on my page. I cannot integrate the slideshow with my application as I haven't built it on a framework. For iframes how can I automatically overcome the scrollbars and other problems?

Comment: wich slideshow are you useing? tell the name or show your code and i will help.

Comment: Just a quick tip: can you try to give your questions less ambiguous titles? 'Photo slideshow' really does not tell anyone what the actual problem is and will make it harder for others to find the answer to similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use these settings:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder="no" allowtransparancy="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

`allowtransparancy` prevents the iframe from having a white background (except in IE!), while `frameborder` switches off the border attribute and `scrolling` prevents scrollbars from appearing.

You'll need to edit the width and height via CSS - iframes have a default size which needs to be overwritten to display all your content properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe { overflow:hidden }
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe style="border:0px;" scrollbar=0>
```

if I remember correctly